# How to inject a bean into a servlet Filter in Undertow?

Tags: cdi, servlet-filters, weld, undertow

Is-it possible to inject a bean into a servlet Filter in Undertow?

Comment: Please give us more details.

Answer (score 0):

you probably want to leverage something like Weld Servlet to enable CDI in Undertow standalone.  See also: http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest/en-US/html/environments.html#_undertow